# Ignore global shortcuts when using iTerm

Tags: terminal, keyboard, macos, iterm

I'm using `tmux` in iTerm2. To resize the `tmux` panels, I think I'm supposed to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>+<kbd>Arrows</kbd>.

For example, if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>, it shows all the windows in the current app, probably because it catches the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> shortcut.

How can I fix this, so when I hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> (or another arrow key), the panels will be resized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to fix this is to turn off or change the global shortcut for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>down</kbd>.

You will find it in System Preferences-Keyboard-Shortcuts under "Mission Control".